# Button : interactive save as + custom initial path

Tags: front-end, notebooks, customization, system, menu

Is it possible to create a button

whose action is

"save as... in menu bar" with ***custom*** **initial full path**.

(***custom*** **initial full path** is specified by user.)

Note that if you click `save as... in menu bar`, a windows pops up suggesting certain full path. That full path is initial full path. If you click `save` immediately, then the notebook is saved on the initial full path. But if you want to change the path, you can type another full path and click yes. In this sense,
`save as... in menu bar` is **interactive**.

So I want to create a `save as` button, that is **interactive**,
with ***custom*** **initial full path**,
on a certain notebook.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`SystemDialogInput`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SystemDialogInput.html).

```
NotebookSave[InputNotebook[], SystemDialogInput["FileSave", "C:\\myfile.nb"]]
```

Comment: Great answer and great built-in function!