# Modify save as.. in the menubar (by editing MenuSetup.tr)

Tags: front-end, notebooks, system, save, menu

I use mathematica V 14.0.0.

Is it possible to modify the behavior of `Save as..` in the menubar?

That is, I want to change the **initial full  path**. We see a window just after clicking `Save as..`. The full path seen in that window is **initial full path**. For more :

[Button : interactive save as + custom initial path](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/297505/button-interactive-save-as-custom-initial-path)

I roughly know that features in menubar are closely related with the file `MenuSetup.tr`.

I carefully looked for texts related with `Save as..`, after opening `MenuSetup.tr` in the text editor.

I could find texts related with

`save`
or
`save selection as`

but failed to find texts related with
`Save as..`.

Below is a captured image of a part of `MenuSetup.tr` opened by text editor.

================================================

[image]

================================================

I want to modify the behavior of `Save as..` in the menubar.
Is it related with MenuSetup.tr ?
If not, which file is related?
Or it can be done with very different method or.. impossible.

I've seen that by editing MenuSetup.tr, we can add something new to the menubar :

[Copy clipboard content to mathematica notebook - line break symbol changes](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/249899/copy-clipboard-content-to-mathematica-notebook-line-break-symbol-changes)

So.. I hope this question can also be resolved in the similar way.

Some progress has been made, but note complete :

[Save as custom folder succeeded! But in two steps](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/297619/save-as-custom-folder-succeeded-but-in-two-steps)

Comment: How is this question different from [your previous one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/297459/change-default-save-path-location-of-an-nb-by-code)? (Which doesn't have an appropriate answer yet.)

Comment: I believe that `Save as...` is managed by operating system not by Mathematica.

Comment: I have answered your previous question, so I consider this as a duplicate.

Comment: @Domen, thank you, but the problem is 50% solved. You  succeeded for directory name, but not for file name yet. For more : https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/297459/change-default-save-path-location-of-an-nb-by-code

Comment: @Domen Some progress has been made : https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/297619/save-as-custom-folder-succeeded-but-in-two-steps